# C# System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

i use foreach to read all the image from a folder

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Workspace.InputFolder, "*.*");
        foreach (string imageFile in filePaths)
        {
            // Some Process here, the output are correct, just after output 
               the error happen
        }
```

But it come out error

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
```

Is the problem cause by the foreach loop keep looping after the process finish?
What should i do for releasing the memory?
Thanks.

Comment: It depends greatly on what you are doing with each filename. If you are opening a file, make sure and Dispose() the objects when you are done.

Comment: Can you describe what you do inside the loop?

Comment: You need to post more code, specifically what you're doing inside the foreach loop.  My gut feeling is that you're creating disposable object instances and not disposing of them correctly, but it's not possible to know for sure unless you post some more code.

Comment: i use the image to do OCR that convert the image into digital data.

Comment: So you found the source of memory leakage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your exception, it looks like you're working with objects in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

If you are opening and manipulating an image in your foreach loop, for example, make sure that you call `Dispose()` to release the images resources as soon as you're done with them.  You can, alternatively, wrap this in a `using` statement, ie:

```
    foreach (string imageFile in filePaths)
    {
        using (var image = Image.FromFile(imageFile)
        {
            // Use the image...
        } // Image will get disposed correctly here, now.
    }
```

Be aware that it's not just images that are potentially the problem, but any resource that implements `IDisposable`.  Many of the classes in `System.Drawing` are disposable - make sure that you either access them as above (via using) or call `Dispose()` on them when done.

Comment: i did try your solution but same error message come out, how should i call the Dispose() function?

Comment: @Xuan You'd need to call the `Dispose()` method on all objects that include it, once you've finished using them, inside of your foreach loop.  This is going to include any images, but also potentially your OCR classes, etc.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Thanks for helping, i solve the problem by change the
    *.* 
to specific image file(*.tif).

Comment: Xuan, simply specifying "*.tif" isn't going to fix the root issue.  The problem at hand is that you almost certainly are working with Disposable types, and aren't properly disposing of the instances when you're done processing them.